# pseudo class wont change

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to create pop up links next to a button when that button is clicked. But using the :active selector has been ineffective, as has :hover and other CSS selectors.

I have tried using other selectors such as descandent and sibling.

```css
.stretch { 
 display: none;
 border: groove;
 border-width: thin 0vh thin 0vh;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 position: relative;
}

.Links:active .stretch {
 display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<div class ="Links">
  <button> Links
    <p></p>
  </button> <!--Move arrow & slide function on links-->
  <div class = "stretch">
    <button> 
      <a id = "HLec">Harvard lec: <br> link</a>
    </button>
    <button>
      <a id = "Hex">TLDW: <br> link</a>
    </button>
    <button>
      <a id = "Vox">Vox (Don't skim the recipe): <br> link </a>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "But using the :active selector has been ineffective". ineffective how? you don't really give us a lot to go on :/

Comment: the links don't pop up when the button is clicked

Comment: But they do show up when you click the button. I don't quite understand how its not being "effective"? It's doing just what it's intended to do.

Comment: @Olian04 I think what he wanted is that when the button is clicked it should pop up the links. using `:active` selector is ineffective because it really pop up the links when clicked but after clicked it will be hidden again and it will not remain the links pop up.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**CSS `:target` Selecor**](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_target.asp). to achieve what you wanted.

```css
.stretch { 
 display: none;
 border: groove;
 border-width: thin 0vh thin 0vh;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 position: relative;
}

.stretch:target {
 display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<div class ="Links">
  <a href="#elem-target"> Links
    <p></p>
  </a> <!--Move arrow & slide function on links-->
  <div class = "stretch" id="elem-target">
    <button> 
      <a id = "HLec">Harvard lec: <br> link</a>
    </button>
    <button>
      <a id = "Hex">TLDW: <br> link</a>
    </button>
    <button>
      <a id = "Vox">Vox (Don't skim the recipe): <br> link </a>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

For more info you can visit this [link](https://codeburst.io/css-tips-and-tricks-using-pseudo-class-fa83248bb6e0) to know more.